# Python : Use of the previous value generated from a function in the same function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, shift

I am trying to have a rolling average of all the highs of ['RSIndex'] greater than 52, series will have NaN value if the first ref value is less than 52, but I want to have the previous iterated value of ['high_r'] that the function has generated if any other ref value is less than 52. If, anyone has any solution to this, i ll be really grateful. Thanks

```
def AvgHigh(src, val) :
    for a in range(len(src)) :
        if src[a] > val :
            yield src[a]
        elif src[a] <= val and a == 0 :
            yield np.nan
        elif src[a] <= val and a != 0 :
            yield src[a-1]

df1['high_r'] = pd.Series(AvgHigh(df1['RSIndex'], 52))
df1['RSI_high'] = df1['high_r'].rolling(window = 25, min_periods = 25).mean()
```

Desired Output:

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: i tried this code, but the 2nd elif statement is not giving me what is required, because ref is of the original RSIndex series and not of the series that the function is generating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to simply your codes, as follows:

```
df1['high_r'] = np.where(df1['RSIndex'] > 52, df1['RSIndex'], df1['RSIndex'].shift())
df1['RSI_high'] = df1['high_r'].rolling(window = 25, min_periods = 25).mean()
```

[`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) checks for the condition of first parameter, if the condition is true, it uses values from the second parameter [similar to your `if` statement in the loop].  When the condition is false [similar to your 2 `elif` statements in the loop]., it uses the values from the third parameter.

[`.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) takes the previous row value [similar to your second `elif` statement] and for the first value where there is no previous, it takes the value given by its `fill_value` parameter, which defaults to use `np.nan` for column of numeric values.  As such, it achieves the same effect of your first `elif` to set `np.nan` for first entry.

### Edit

If you want the values to take from last loop iteration instead of initial column values, you can define a list to accumulate the values of the loop, as follows:

```
def AvgHigh(src, val) :
    dat_list = []
    last_src = np.nan              # init variable that keeps the prev iteration value
    for a in range(len(src)) :
        if src[a] > val :
#            yield src[a]
            dat_list.append(src[a])
            last_src = src[a]          # update prev iteration value (for subsequent iteration(s))
        elif (src[a] <= val) and (a == 0) :
#            yield np.nan
            dat_list.append(np.nan)
        elif (src[a] <= val) and (a != 0) :
#            yield src[a-1]
            dat_list.append(last_src)
        
    return dat_list

df1['high_r'] = AvgHigh(df1['RSIndex'], 52)
df1['RSI_high'] = df1['high_r'].rolling(window = 25, min_periods = 25).mean()
```

Comment: I am really grateful, that you mentioned about this , surely i ll be using it, since this is much smaller and efficient code, but one thing is still missed out,
`df1['high_r'] = np.where(df1['RSIndex'] > 52, df1['RSIndex'], df1['RSIndex'].shift())`
in this, when first parameter is false, i dont want the RSIndex previoius value, i want the previous value of df1['high_r']

Comment: as in the example
list = 78,49,45,51,64
the result would be = 78,78,49,45,64
what i want = 78,78,78,78,64

Comment: @r_goel  In this case, you can use `df1['high_r'].shift()` in the third parameter instead of `df1['RSIndex'].shift()`

Comment: @r_goel  So, you want the values to take from last iteration instead of initial column values, right ?

Comment: right, yes i meant that. last iteration is the right word.
right now, running the code is giving me keyError: 'high_r'

Comment: @r_goel  I see, seems like you have to use a loop then.  I will try to get a solution for this.

Comment: sry but its doing the same thing as before, since in second elif statement, the code is appending the previous columns previous value and not the previous iterated value of the same column

`elif src[a] <= val and a != 0 :
#            yield src[a-1]
            dat_list.append(src[a-1])
    return dat_list`

Comment: @r_goel  I have further updated the code to use `last_src`.  See the latest version.

Comment: @r_goel  Better also to put more brackets around different boolean condition in the `elif` statements.  See my edit.

Comment: nope @SeaBean, its giving me the same thing as before.
[output](https://ibb.co/zRNfXjQ)

Comment: @r_goel  Probably, you want to update the prev value only when the current loop value is > 52.   See my edit above.  I have tested with your sample data 78,49,45,51,64 and got the expected result 78,78,78,78,64

Comment: Yes, i got the desired result, all thanks to you @SeaBean, thanks for putting in your good time.
I am new to this, I surely upvote this when i reach the minimum reputation.

Comment: @r_goel  I would suggest you also update the question to make it clearer.  Especially, the sample data list and the expected result out of that.